# Serving pre-compressed Angular dist files over Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I compress all files under `dist` folder and try to serve the `gzip` files over Nginx.

Below is my nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        root  /PATH_TO_DIST_FOLDER/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.html.gz;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip_static on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_vary on;
        gunzip on;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml applicat$

        location / {
                expires 1y;
                access_log off;
                add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31556952, public";
                add_header  Content-Encoding  gzip;

                try_files $uri  $uri/ /index.html.gz;
        }
}
```

The problem:

It loads the gzipped `index.html` file at first correctly.

And the `index.html` will loads the resources like `main.js`, `polyfills.js`, `styles.css`, etc.

But the request to get `main.js` returns the content of the `index.html` again.

I have only `gzip` files under the dist directory.

I think the `try_files` doesnt find the matching `gzip` file.

Could you anyone help me how I can solve this problem?

**Update**

If I update the configuration like below:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        root  /PATH_TO_DIST_FOLDER/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.html.gz;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
                expires 1y;
                access_log off;
                add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31556952, public";

                gzip_static always;
                gzip_proxied any;

                try_files $uri  $uri/ /index.html.gz;
        }
}
```

It just downloads the `gzip` file of the index.html.

Comment: `try_files` is not `gzip_static` aware, so `$uri` is not looking for the `$uri.gz` version of the file. As you don't have both versions of the file present on disk, you could try: `try_files $uri  $uri.gz $uri/ /index.html.gz;`

Comment: i have tried that too, but didnt work..

Comment: I have one more suggestion, try replacing the `try_files` statement with `if (!-e $request_filename.gz) { rewrite ^ /index.html last; }` (I've deliberately removed the `.gz` from `index.html`)

Comment: OK I will try that

Comment: could you check my updated question?

Comment: You may need to use `/index.html` with `gzip_static always;` and allow Nginx to append the `.gz` itself.